# Access to controller's param in Ember view

Tags: ember.js

Let's say I have `IndexController` and it has a param called `isEditing`.

I also have `index` template which `{{render list}}` template.

I have a problem in using `isEditing` property in `list`.

You can find an example here http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kabumuca/1/edit

Did I miss something here?

Answer (score 1):

Ahoy!

So, here is the working jsbin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kabumuca/9/edit.

Essentially, the reason why it wasn't working was because of a misinterpretation of the view helpers.  When you're using the `{{render}}` helper, it ties your controller to the view you are rendering.  As you weren't specifying a literal view (just the template and model), it was creating virtual view and controller for you.

See here: [The Render Helper - Ember.js](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/#toc_the-code-render-code-helper)

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
App.ListController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  isEditing: Ember.computed.alias('parentController.isEditing')
});
```